# iOS Metal Invalid device store executing vertex function "myFunction" encoder: draw: offset:

Tags: ios, shader, swift5, metal

I have a project using Metal rendering, it is working fine when I pass one metal buffer to the shader function. However, when I pass a different buffer, I get the following errors:

```
(IOAF code 11)
with "Shader validation enabled" scheme diagnostic flag:

Invalid device store executing vertex function "myFunction" encoder: draw: offset:
```

Both buffers are initialized using the same function. The lifecycle of the first object holding the buffer is much longer than the second one.

**Is the error caused by the object holding the buffer being deallocated?**

```
/// Initializes the buffer with zeros, the buffer is given an appropriate length based on the provided element count.
    init(device: MTLDevice, count: Int, index: UInt32, label: String? = nil, options: MTLResourceOptions = []) {
        
        guard let buffer = device.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<Element>.stride * count, options: options) else {
            fatalError("Failed to create MTLBuffer.")
        }
        self.buffer = buffer
        self.buffer.label = label
        self.count = count
        self.index = Int(index)
    }

 //usage:
 renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(/*one of two buffers*/)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the shader function trying to write the output of it's calculation at a wrong index. **As long as the shader references the buffer from 0 to count, everything works with either buffer.** The error was caused by the shader trying to reference the buffer using a wrong index, and stepping out of range of the buffer.

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer as a solution. And a couple remarks regarding your assumptions: 1) as long as you don't create your command buffer as command buffer with unretained references, you can't really deallocate anything that you used to encode a command (besides objects used indirectly, in which case you need to `useResource` them or `useHeap`, so it will still be alive. 2) when posting questions about buffers it's useful to provide the shader because it's kinda hard to guess what the error is without knowing what shader does.

Comment: Thank you, I will post shaders for subsequent questions, I have to wait 2 days to accept the answer.